# meaning of the compound word "low-draw"?

Tags: meaning

Here is the context:

> Primary AA batteries use cheaper materials and are great for **low-draw** devices.

I have looked it up on the internet, but no results came up.

Comment: idiom: to draw current from a source. Adjective: low-draw.....:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Low-draw devices" simply means devices that demand little current from the battery - a hand-held calculator for instance.
But really, that sweeping statement as quoted isn't entirely true.  'AA' is a form factor, not a capacity, and the ability of an AA battery to supply higher currents depends on the technology used. [see for instance the chart on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AA_battery)

Answer (score 2):

To augment peterG's correct answer...

Let's take a look at the following:

> This device **resonates** a lot.
>
> This is a high-**resonance** device.
>
> This device **draws** very little current.
>
> This is a low-**draw** device.

A noun can be formed from the verb:

resonate -> resonance

draw -> draw

Some English verbs are of Latinate origin (**resonate**) while others are of Germanic origin (**draw**).

The formation of nouns from Latinate verbs follows Latinate rules, from Germanic verbs, Germanic rules.